# Csv, как преобразовать русские символы в латиницу?

Tags: excel, csv, макрос

Имеется файл таблицы в формате `.csv`, допустим с данными для импорта товаров в магазин. В колонке `C` название товаров, а в колонке `AB` нужно переделать это название товара в латиницу для сео. Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать такой макрос?
С программированием для `excel` вообще не знаком.

**P.S.**
нашёл похожий код. Подскажите, как его исправить?

```
Sub DC0()
Const rus = "АВЕКМНОРСТУХЬавекмнорстухь"
Const lat = "ABEKMHOPCTYXBabekmhopctyxb"
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Len(rus)
  Selection.Replace What:=Mid(rus, i, 1), Replacement:=Mid(lat, i, 1), 
   LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub DC0()
Dim i As Long
Const rus As String = "АВЕКМНОРСТУХЬавекмнорстухь"
Const lat As String = "ABEKMHOPCTYXBabekmhopctyxb"
    Columns("C:C").Copy Columns("AB:AB")

    For i = 1 To Len(rus)
        Columns("AB:AB").Replace What:=Mid$(rus, i, 1), Replacement:=Mid$(lat, i, 1), _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Если символ заменять на несколько (или наоборот), вместо строковых констант нужно применять массивы

```
Sub DC0()
Dim aRus(), aLat()
Dim i As Long
    aRus = Array("А", "В", "я", "ь")
    aLat = Array("A", "B", "ya", "b")

    Columns("C:C").Copy Columns("AB:AB")

    For i = 0 To UBound(aRus)
        Columns("AB:AB").Replace What:=aRus(i), Replacement:=aLat(i), _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Показано полное копирование столбца и замена во всех копированных данных. Ограничение или определение диапазона копирования здесь не рассматривается.

Comment: подскажите, допустим русская буква "я" на латинице будет "ya", ваш код не будет корректно работать предполагаю, и где в вашем коде указывается колонка `C`, в которой названия товаров ?

Comment: Был ошибочно вставлен не тот код. Если символ заменять на несколько (или наоборот),  вместо строковых констант нужно применять массивы

Comment: а можете показать, как работать с массивами, потому-что с excel вообще не знаком?

Comment: Дополнил ответ...

Comment: благодарю, а не затруднит ещё добавить, как пропустить первый ряд из excel? т.к. в 1м ряду названия колонок

Comment: Проще добавить после замены: `Range("AB1").Value = Range("C1").Value`

Comment: а не затруднит вас подсказать, как всё-таки пропустить первый ряд, в котором названия колонок? сейчас изучаю vba, никак не могу придумать, как это сделать программно, в этих колонках будут разные названия, такой вариант не подходит `Range("AB1").Value = Range("C1").Value`

Comment: Вместо *Columns("AB:AB").Replace...* указывать конкретный диапазон столбца: *Range("AB2:AB25").Replace...*

Comment: поставил диапазон, но выдаёт 400 ошибку, как это исправить?

Comment: Правильно и без ошибок править код. *Range* вместо *Columns* - это касалось строки в цикле